# How to not receive UDP datagrams for the wrong subnet but still broadcasts?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp, posix

I have an interface eth0 set up as 168.152.32.222 with netmask 255.255.255.0.

My server application wants to receive now UDP datagrams with the following destination addresses on eth0:

1. 168.152.32.222
2. 168.152.32.255
3. 255.255.255.255

This seems like a rather reasonable request, yet I can't get the socket bound properly.

- If I bind to 168.152.32.222, I don't receive the broadcasts.
- If I bind to INADDR_ANY, I get datagrams from all interfaces.
- If I bind to INADDR_ANY and SO_BINDTODEVICE, I get packets which arrive on eth0 for different subnets, like 168.152.47.x.

In theory, I could just accept the datagrams and then filter all wrong packets out on my own with the netmask again - but seriously, some lower layer should do this, that's somehow the point of the netmask.

**How to not receive UDP datagrams for the wrong subnet but still broadcasts?**

A solution outside the server application is acceptable, too. I'm considering filtering the packets with iptables, not sure if this is feasible though and it would be the last resort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your application server and if you don't care about other udp packets, you can set iptables rules like this :

```
iptables -F # flush filter rules
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -s 168.152.32.0/24 -d 162.152.32.222/32 -j ACCEPT # accept udp packets from 168.152.32.0/24 network to 162.152.32.222 host
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -s 168.152.32.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j ACCEPT # accept udp packets from 168.152.32.0/24 network to 255.255.255.255/32 broadcast address 
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -s 168.152.32.0/24 -d 168.152.32.255/32 -j ACCEPT # accept udp packets from 168.152.32.0/24 network to 168.152.32.255/32 broadcast address
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -j DROP # drop all other incoming udp packets
```

Or you should consider to accept all the broadcasted packets and then filter manualy the src addresses of your network in your code. The size of your network is small, may be filtering with IP_ADD_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP setsockopt option is enough for you.